Component identification - what are these two blue blobs
What are these two handsome brothers?

In case you can't see them properly, they are polar components, both marked with "+2,2" and "+25V" tags.

Two tantalum caps still waiting to be soldered correctly to the board.

Those are dipped tantalum capacitors. 2.2 µF at 25 V.
They are polarized as noted by the + signs on one side.

[You can use a μ instead of the incongruous MathJax version.]

@AndrewMorton I can never remember the darned alt codes but I know the latex codes. Fixed.

I know what you mean. I just have an HTML document within easy reach with a few of those useful symbols.

Thank you very much, GodJihyo
